# algorithm - How would you determine the minimum number of multiplications to evaluate X to the power 30?

Tags: algorithm, multiplication

In the book [Algorithms for interviewers](http://www.algorithmsforinterviews.com/), there is such a question:

> How would you determine the minimum number of multiplications to evaluate X to the power 30?

Can anyone tell me what this question means?

What means "evaluate X to the power 30"?

There are two possible meanings, i guess:

1. we have a X, then this question asks me "how many multiplications do I need to calculate X^30?".
2. We have a X, then it asks me "What y is so that y^30 = X, and how many multiplications do you need to calculate y?"

I don't know which of what I guess is correct, or it has a 3rd meaning?

Thanks

Comment: The first meaning is correct. The second meaning would mean finding the thirtieth root of X.

Comment: It is worth noting (since this is an interview question), that to compute the minimum number of multiplications when using Addition-chain exponentiation (which gives the answer of 6 for x^30), is an NP-complete problem and is more memory intensive compared to other methods.

Comment: Also interesting that you can compute x^32 in five multiplications then divide by x twice.  (Hey, it's only five _multiplications_!)  Or just increment zero x^30 times as Kaganar suggests.  Or just use function calls and Church numerals...  So you need to say more -- a lot more -- even to make this question well-defined.

Comment: If it's one of those silly interview questions that has some "trick" to it, the answer is obviously zero -- all you need is a Turing complete computation environment, and you can provide that with much less than multiplication. (See "BrainFuck", for example.) I've posted an answer below that uses no multiplication -- or addition.

Comment: Also note that it doesn't matter what X is - the set of operations is the same regardless. Which may seem obvious, but the OP phrases it like he's expecting a specific X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question supposes that there is a way to write a function:

```
int f(int x) { return pow(x, 30); }
```

using only multiplications.

In fact one way would be the following:

```
int f(int x)
{
    int y = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        y *= x;
    return y;
}
```

This uses 30 multiplications.

However consider this:

```
int f(int x)
{
    int z = x*x;
    int y = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        y *= z;
    return y;
}
```

This uses 16 multiplications.

So the question is asking what is the minimum number of multiplications possible?

Here is 6 multiplications, and likely the interviewers ideal solution:

```
int f(int x)
{
    x_3 = x * x * x;
    x_6 = x_3 * x_3;
    x_12 = x_6 * x_6
    x_24 = x_12 * x_12
    return x_24 * x_6
}
```

This is more a brainteaser than a programming problem.  A real power function does not use multiplication (or at least not in the way implied by the question)

Comment: If asked "How many additions does it take to calcualte X * 30?" would you answer "30 additions?"

Comment: There seems to be a solution with 6 multiplications (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation , take the n=15 in the table and add one multiplication for the squaring). The problem in general is hard.

Comment: Why do you say it's just a brainteaser? I could see this coming in handy when multiplication is an expensive operation, e.g. when X represents a large matrix. Although the problem is np-complete, the running time is w.r.t. the power of X, which could be much smaller than the size of the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of x^30 there is good special method - only 6 multiplications: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation. Exponentiation by squaring is good enough in most cases.

Comment: Nice.  Might be worth linking to [a table that actually includes 30](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/addition_chain.html), though.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this is with repeated doubling, which other people have shown takes 7 multiplications.  Depending on the number, though, it can be done with fewer multiplications.  In this case you can do it in as few as 6:

```
x3 = x * x * x
x6 = x3 * x3
x12 = x6 * x6
x24 = x12 * x12
x30 = x24 * x6
```

Answer (score 3):

Heh, an amusing note is technically the answer to the question is 'zero'. You can use zero multiplications, assuming we're working with floats, doubles, ints, etc.. After all, you can emulate any of these operations with just integer math, and you can emulate integer math with increment/decrement. So, here's a version for integers that only uses increment (and comparisons):

```
// This runs faster than you might think -- this gets optimized fairly well by GCC.

int fakeUnsignedIntegerAdd(int a, int b)
{
    int i = 0, c = a;
    for (; i < b; i++, c++);
    return c;
}

int fakeUnsignedIntegerMul(int a, int b)
{
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    for (; i < b; i++, c = fakeUnsignedIntegerAdd(c, a));
    return c;
}

int fakeUnsignedIntegerPow(unsigned int b, unsigned int e)
{
    int i = 0, c = 1;
    for (; i < e; i++, c = fakeUnsignedIntegerMul(c, b));
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%i\n", fakeUnsignedIntegerPow(2, 30));
    return 0;
}
```

... Although that's probably not what they had in mind. Or maybe it is -- some interview questions are intentionally misleading to see if you're "insightful".

Comment: I've implemented this and it runs exponentially slower than normal addition when using g++ and unsigned int:
template<class T>
T addSpecial(T a, T b) {
 T i = 0, c = a;
 for(;i<b;i++,c++);
 return c;
}

Answer (score 1):

I think it shall be the first one and you can use exponentiation by squaring to reduce the number of multiplications based on the name of book.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Comment: Very good. In this case, you can do `x^30` as `x^16 * x^8 * x^4 * x^2`. You only actually need seven multiplications for this.

Comment: The other sneaky way is to do `x^m = e^(log(x)*m)` which works really well for really large `m` (so long as you don't mind a bit more error than you would get from doing the FMULs.)

Answer (score 0):

Exponentiation by squaring is a nice, general algorithm, but it will give you 7 multiplications.  This particular problem can be done using 6:

```
x2 = x*x
x3 = x2*x
x5 = x2*x3
x10 = x5*x5
x20 = x10*x10
x30 = x20*x10
```